# Cannot open .rpt files after last windows updates

Tags: windows, dao, crystal-reports-2010

After last day's Windows 10 updates, we have issue to open Access file by Crystal Report.

I faced this problem after windows 10 updates on 08/Jan/2018.
When I try to open a .rpt files, I get this error:

Error:

```
Query Engine Error: 'DAO Error Code: 0xd0f  
Source: DAO.Fields
Description: Unrecognized database format 'C:\MyTable.MDB'.')
```

.rpt files are using MyTable.MDB ( Ver 2.0 !!!!)

The list of updates:

```
KB4480961
KB4480973
KB4480978
KB4480966
KB4480970
KB4480116
KB4480962
KB4480963
KB4480975
KB4468742
KB4471389
```

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unrecognized-database-format-after-january-2019/a2518bb6-050d-4e7b-8844-257dbc6a20a2

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution guys.
Just modify the .rpt connection using ODCB(RDO) could fix the issue.